# Spring aggregrator stops processing when message is missing

Tags: spring-integration

Hello and thanks in advance for checking this question.

We have a file based spring integration (4.3.19.RELEASE) pipeline, where an zip is taken, extracted and each csv file is processed in the pipeline. 
These are altered and then imported via some custom logic into the database.

**The Problem:**
we have a case where the aggregator does not receveice its expected number of messages and cancels the process silently (does not call the next channel/service-activator)

**The spring-integration pipeline:**

- reads 48 CSV files
- Enriches some header data
- processes (with splitter) the csv files.
- some more header header enrichment
- several service-activator (one after another)
- header-value-router -> sends message to "subaggregator" (default) and "pimAggrator" in case of an special header (code example below)
  -> subaggregator simply forwards to "pimAggrator"
- "pimAggrator" forwards to service-activator (this does not happen in the described problem here)

## Debugging so far:

The Aggregator uses the default "SequenceSizeReleaseStrategy".

As far as i understood the Strategy, it release the channel when the received message count reaches the sequence count.

I've set a breakpoint in the "if"-line

```
int sequenceSize = messageGroup.getSequenceSize();
// If there is no sequence then it must be incomplete....
    if (sequenceSize == size) {
    canRelease = true;
    }
```

- The sequence count seems to be the number of incoming files (the count of extracted files from the unzip channel).
- CSV Files (e.g. 10) are processed.
- if such an csv files contains the header of the csv only (= no data lines), then the new csv file is not written to the disk for further processing.
- the "pimAggregatorChannel" (mentioned before) expects 10 Messages but receives only 9 messages (because 1 file had no datalines and hence was not written to the disk for further processing).
- the "pimAggregatorChannel" does not continue to the following service activator.
- i haven't found any exceptions regarding this.

```
... file polling. csv proprozessing (e.g. substititung values).... 

<!-- 5.1 move the files (= ZIP entries) to processing and re-configure output directories -->
<file:outbound-gateway request-channel="pimFileProcessingChannel" 
    reply-channel="pimFileHeaderSetupChannel"
    directory="#{baseDirectoryPim}/processing" delete-source-files="true"/>

.... a bunch of service-activators, processing the files. (mostly data enrichment for further processing) ....


<int:header-value-router input-channel="pimAggregationRoutingChannel"
     default-output-channel="pimSubAggregatorChannel"
     resolution-required="false"
     header-name="#{T(...PimFileHeaders).FILETYPE}">
     <int:mapping value="#{T(...PimFileType).ITEM.name()}"
          channel="pimAggregatorChannel"/>
</int:header-value-router>

<int:aggregator input-channel="pimSubAggregatorChannel"
    output-channel="pimAggregatorChannel"/>

<int:aggregator input-channel="pimAggregatorChannel"
    output-channel="pimPerformCleanUpDbChannel"/>
```

## Comments added for your understading

```
// this methods contains the logic for the splitting messages / writing the new files/message payloads. 
    public final List<Message<byte[]>> preProcessCsv(final Message<byte[]> message) throws IOException {
        final String originalFilename = (String) message.getHeaders().get(FileHeaders.FILENAME);
        // dataPerKey is an empty Map for the csv file which contains no data
        final Map<String, byte[]> dataPerKey = processPayload(message);

        // hence no splitMessages will be generated.
        final List<Message<byte[]>> splitMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        if (MapUtils.isNotEmpty(dataPerKey)) {
            createNewMessages(originalFilename, dataPerKey, splitMessages);
        }
        // returns the empty obviously empty list. 
        return splitMessages;
    }
```

The following debug message is written to the console is the case mentioned above, when the csv file which is processed does not contain datalines:

```
[MethodInvokingSplitter] handler 'pimFileNavigationTextpoolRefChain$child#0.handler' produced no reply for request Message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[59], headers={file_name_original=310_NavigationRefTextpool.csv, zip_entryPath=, sequenceNumber=21, zip_name=P_pim_import4189562333325735125.zip, file_name=NavigationRefTextpool-1564409172681.csv, sequenceSize=48, file_type=NAVIGATION_TEXTPOOL_REFERENCE, correlationId=43450967-5c51-105b-172b-9093f8e2b3e9, history=pimZipInputChannel,pimUnzipChannel,pimFileFormatChannel,pimFileFormatChain,pimFileRoutingChannel,pimFileNavigationTextpoolRefChannel,pimFileNavigationTextpoolRefChain, id=23e40731-eb8a-3411-541a-65fe56b552b4, timestamp=1564409172682}]
```

**Actual behavior:**

- The Pipeline does not continue, when an csv file does not contain any data lines, after "pimAggregatorChannel".

**Expected/wanted behavior:**

- I want the "pimAggregatorChannel" to still call the service activator and not cancel silently.
- There is nothing to do when the file does not contain any data, actually this a a valid situation.

Thanks again for reading and helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to always write the file, even if it's empty.

As long as everything is processed sequentially (no `QueueChannel`s or `ExecutorChannel`s) then the next simplest would be a custom release strategy.

The `SequenceSizeReleaseStrategy` simply looks at the message group size.

A custom release strategy can look at the sequence number header of the last message in the group and release when the sequence number equals the sequence size.

That will work for all cases except when the last file is "empty" and therefore missing.

You can handle that condition with a group timeout - if no more messages arrive the partial group can be released.

Or, you can just use the group timeout without a custom release strategy and always release based on the timeout.

Comment: Hello Gary, and thank you very much for answering, i will closely review this answer and think about the solutions and will come back soon with an acceptance or further questions ;-).

Comment: Thanks for the help Gary,

we are going for the "The simplest solution is to always write the file, even if it's empty." solution. 

But we are not sending a file, i understood now how we can handle "corrupt" data. This solution brought me to the right track. 
We are creating a "Corrupt/Empty" Data Message.